# Add Intents to Luis programmatically

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-language-understanding

I need to add `Intents` to my `Luis` app using `c#` code. In the MS docs there is only examples of adding utterances programmatically. However I tried to do it on my own. So I navigated to my app in the browser and then added a new Intent and inspected the network tab and got the `Post` request like this:

uri : 
https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/App_ID/versions/0.1/intents

the request body like this (where "testIntent" is the name of the added intent):

```
{
  "name": "testIntent"
}
```

Then I wrote following code:

```
class Program
{ 
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
                AddIntent().Wait();
      }

      async static Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendPost(string uri, string requestBody)
      {
             using (var client = new HttpClient())
             using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
             {
                 request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
                 request.RequestUri = new Uri(uri);

                 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(requestBody))
                 {
                     request.Content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "text/json");
                 }

              request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", authoringKey);
                 return await client.SendAsync(request);
             }
       }

       async static Task AddIntent()
       {
            string uri = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/App_ID/versions/0.1/intents";
            string requestBody = File.ReadAllText("json.json");
            var response = await SendPost(uri, requestBody);
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(JsonFormatter.Format(result));
       }
}
```

and `json.json` file looks like this:

```
[
    {
      "name": "Intent from c# code!"
    }
]
```

I'm getting the error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadArgument",
        "message": "Failed to parse classifier creation object. Parameter name: classifierCreateObject"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can Luis intent names contain spaces and special characters?

Comment: yes! they can :) Solution found! take a look at the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See LUIS API documentation here, for `Create Intent` method: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c0c

The body should be like the following:

```
{
    "name": "BookFlight"
}
```

In your case you provided an array with 1 item.

Correct it and it will be working (see below):

[image]